# Same keybind for multiple commands (shortcuts) vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to have the same command for multiple actions on vscode like run/stop on `.py`, same on a notebook, but when I add the `cmd+enter` keybind for one shortcut, the other stops working. I found it pretty random, sometimes it works sometimes not, yesterday it worked and I just opened my project, didn't work...

I've checked the `JSON` files `Default Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and `Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` but everything seems to be fine.

Anyone that went through a similar experience or has a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Secondary shortcut may not work because in the json file `Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`, when setting a new shortcut, you have a condition `where`.

This file is the user keybind file and will store all the shortcuts you set or remove. For the removed ones (the default that you change), they have a minus in front of the command name.

To set a new shortcut you need to specify the when.

```
{
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "workbench.action.debug.stop",
    "when": "!notebookEditorFocused && inDebugMode"
},
{
    "key": "shift+f5",
    "command": "-workbench.action.debug.stop",
    "when": "inDebugMode && !focusedSessionIsAttach"
}
```